# Read Line by Line Alternative Spark

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to read line by line for a use case, I need to read the data from header and send to all the records between Header and Trailer Spark doesn't allow reading line by line - How do we implement such a use case.

```
*H,TextStart,1244
I,000000001,GOOD,-000000001,DMGD,+000000000,SOM ,00002,+000000000,ONHAND              ,LCU       ,
I,000000062,GOOD,+000000004,DMGD,+000000000,SOM ,00001,+000000000,ONHAND              ,LCU       ,
*T,TextEnd
*H,TextStart,1235
I,000000002,GOOD,-000000001,DMGD,+000000000,SOM ,00002,+000000000,ONHAND              ,LCU       ,
I,000000035,GOOD,+000000004,DMGD,+000000000,SOM ,00001,+000000000,ONHAND              ,LCU       ,
*T,TextEnd
*H,TextStart,1244
I,000000004,GOOD,-000000001,CRT,+000000000,SOM ,00002,+000000000,ONHAND              ,LCU       ,
I,000000062,GOOD,+000000004,DPT,+000000000,SOM ,00001,+000000000,ONHAND              ,LCU       ,
*T,TextEnd
*H,TextStart,1236
I,000000005,GOOD,-000000001,ABCD,+000000000,SOM ,00002,+000000000,ONHAND              ,LCU       ,
I,000000035,GOOD,+000000004,EFGF,+000000000,SOM ,00001,+000000000,ONHAND              ,LCU       ,
*T,TextEnd
```

The expected output is taking data from header and attach to the header and tailer records. I am not sure how

```
1244,I,000000001,GOOD,-000000001,DMGD,+000000000,SOM ,00002,+000000000,ONHAND              ,LCU,    
1244,I,000000062,GOOD,+000000004,DMGD,+000000000,SOM ,00001,+000000000,ONHAND              ,LCU,    
1235,I,000000002,GOOD,-000000001,DMGD,+000000000,SOM ,00002,+000000000,ONHAND              ,LCU,    
1236,I,000000035,GOOD,+000000004,DMGD,+000000000,SOM ,00001,+000000000,ONHAND              ,LCU,    
1244,I,000000004,GOOD,-000000001,CRT,+000000000,SOM ,00002,+000000000,ONHAND              ,LCU ,    
1244,I,000000062,GOOD,+000000004,DPT,+000000000,SOM ,00001,+000000000,ONHAND              ,LCU ,    
1236,I,000000005,GOOD,-000000001,ABCD,+000000000,SOM ,00002,+000000000,ONHAND              ,LCU,    
1236,I,000000035,GOOD,+000000004,EFGF,+000000000,SOM ,00001,+000000000,ONHAND              ,LCU,
```

I used zip index and got the line numbers populated.

```
df = spark.read.text('/hdfsData/file.csv')
df_1 = df.rdd.map(lambda r: r).zipWithIndex().toDF(['value', 'index'])
df_11 = spark.sql("select value.value ,index from linenumber where value.value like '*H,%' or value.value like '*T,%'")
```

Now I am planning to join df_11 and df_1 and do some range join logic to pick value. But is there any other efficient way to get the same?

Comment: Do you expect all headers and trailers to be in the shown format? If yes, you should be able to use `regexp_extract` with multiple splits and explodes.

Comment: Edited the order of data so that everyone dont have to scroll to see the header adding to the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented the same using zip index and window lag functions. However this will be done in single partition as the nature of the data demands it. Provide appropriate executor memory.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = spark.read.text('MQ_out.csv')
#Adding index column each row get its row numbers 
df_1 = df.rdd.map(lambda r: r).zipWithIndex().toDF(['value', 'index'])
df_1.createOrReplaceTempView("linenumber")
#zipindex creates array making back to string
df_2 = spark.sql("select value.value as value , index  from linenumber")
df_2.createOrReplaceTempView("linenumber1")
df_3 = spark.sql("select * from linenumber1 where value is not null or trim(value)!=''")
df_3.createOrReplaceTempView("linenumber2")
#Splitting and extracting the location value from header and assigning null
df_new = spark.sql("select value,case when value like '*H,%' then split(value,',')[2] else null end as location,index from linenumber2")
#Assign previous row value to next row if the current row is null
df_new=df_new.withColumn('newlocation',F.when(df_new.location>0,df_new.location).otherwise(F.last(df_new.location,ignorenulls=True).over(Window.orderBy("index"))))
#counting the number of , in data
df_new.withColumn('Comma_Count', size(split(col("value"), r",")) - 1)
df_new.createOrReplaceTempView("FinalData")
#remove Header and tralierrows which doesnt have needed number of commans
df_final=spark.sql("select value,newlocation as location from FinalData where Comma_Count = 11")
df_final.createOrReplaceTempView("FinalData_1")
#concat to bring the required data
df_write = spark.sql("select concat(value,newlocation) from FinalData_1")
df_write.text('Filename')
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the file into a RDD

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/sf0.txt")
```

Then split each lines of the files by comma and filter out the header and trailer.

```
val rdd2 = rdd.map(x => x.split(",")).filter(x => x(0) != "*H" && x(0) != "*T")
```

Next, convert the array into a tuple which can be converted to a dataframe. If we skip this step out dataframe will have only one column with all the contents in an array.

```
val finalRDD = rdd2.map(x => (x(0), x(1), x(2), x(3), x(4), x(5), x(6), x(7), x(8), x(9), x(10)))
```

Convert the RDD to dataframe

```
val myDF = finalRDD.toDF()
```

Check dataframe contents:

```
myDF.show()

+---+---------+----+----------+----+----------+----+-----+----------+--------------------+----------+
| _1|       _2|  _3|        _4|  _5|        _6|  _7|   _8|        _9|                 _10|       _11|
+---+---------+----+----------+----+----------+----+-----+----------+--------------------+----------+
|  I|000000001|GOOD|-000000001|DMGD|+000000000|SOM |00002|+000000000|ONHAND              |LCU       |
|  I|000000062|GOOD|+000000004|DMGD|+000000000|SOM |00001|+000000000|ONHAND              |LCU       |
|  I|000000002|GOOD|-000000001|DMGD|+000000000|SOM |00002|+000000000|ONHAND              |LCU       |
|  I|000000035|GOOD|+000000004|DMGD|+000000000|SOM |00001|+000000000|ONHAND              |LCU       |
|  I|000000004|GOOD|-000000001| CRT|+000000000|SOM |00002|+000000000|ONHAND              |LCU       |
|  I|000000062|GOOD|+000000004| DPT|+000000000|SOM |00001|+000000000|ONHAND              |LCU       |
|  I|000000005|GOOD|-000000001|ABCD|+000000000|SOM |00002|+000000000|ONHAND              |LCU       |
|  I|000000035|GOOD|+000000004|EFGF|+000000000|SOM |00001|+000000000|ONHAND              |LCU       |
+---+---------+----+----------+----+----------+----+-----+----------+--------------------+----------+
```

Comment: The challenge was to add the header row to its corresponding rows between header and trailer.  I am close to a solution using zip index and window partition logic with Lag function. The last column in the output.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it by using two `lag` functions

```py
(df
    .withColumn('id', F.monotonically_increasing_id())            # make fake ID for window functions below
    .withColumn('lag_1', F.lag('value', 1).over(W.orderBy('id'))) # grab the previous row (offset 1)
    .withColumn('lag_2', F.lag('value', 2).over(W.orderBy('id'))) # grab the previous row (offset 2)
    .withColumn('heading', F                                      # make heading column based on availability of both lag_1 and lag_2
        .when(F.col('lag_1').startswith('*H,TextStart'), F.col('lag_1'))
        .when(F.col('lag_2').startswith('*H,TextStart'), F.col('lag_2'))
    )
    .where(F.col('heading').isNotNull())                          # remove header and trailer rows, which does not have proper heading
    .withColumn('value', F.concat(F.split(F.col('heading'), ',')[2], F.lit(','), F.col('value')))
                                                                  # concatenate heading number with current value
    .drop('id', 'lag_1', 'lag_2', 'heading')                      # remove temporary columns
    .show(20, False)
)

# +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |value                                                                                                  |
# +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |1244,I,000000001,GOOD,-000000001,DMGD,+000000000,SOM ,00002,+000000000,ONHAND              ,LCU       ,|
# |1244,I,000000062,GOOD,+000000004,DMGD,+000000000,SOM ,00001,+000000000,ONHAND              ,LCU       ,|
# |1235,I,000000002,GOOD,-000000001,DMGD,+000000000,SOM ,00002,+000000000,ONHAND              ,LCU       ,|
# |1235,I,000000035,GOOD,+000000004,DMGD,+000000000,SOM ,00001,+000000000,ONHAND              ,LCU       ,|
# |1244,I,000000004,GOOD,-000000001,CRT,+000000000,SOM ,00002,+000000000,ONHAND              ,LCU       , |
# |1244,I,000000062,GOOD,+000000004,DPT,+000000000,SOM ,00001,+000000000,ONHAND              ,LCU       , |
# |1236,I,000000005,GOOD,-000000001,ABCD,+000000000,SOM ,00002,+000000000,ONHAND              ,LCU       ,|
# |1236,I,000000035,GOOD,+000000004,EFGF,+000000000,SOM ,00001,+000000000,ONHAND              ,LCU       ,|
# +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```